# send_file() giving error saying invalid mode 'rb'

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I am converting a Python script to an .exe file using `pyinstaller`. Then using `send_file()` in Flask, I am sending it to the client. I am getting an error:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:
>   'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\mummy\dist\tc.exe'

Here `tc.exe` is the executable I want to send and it's located in the dist folder.

This code doesn't give any error and gets send using send_file:

```
import subprocess
print ("hi")
subprocess.call('ipconfig > zzz.txt', shell = True)
x = raw_input()
```

But my code (it checks whether system has python installed) gives error:

```
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call('python -V 2> z1.txt' , shell = True)
var1 = subprocess.call('find /i "not recognized" z1.txt', shell = True)
subprocess.call('del z1.txt' , shell = True)
if(var1 == 0):
    print ("python not found")
else:
    print ("python found")
x=raw_input()
```

(It calls the python version in the cmd prompt and stores it in a text file. Then it checks whether "not found" keyword is present in the text file. If it's present that means python is not installed)

The raw_input() is given for the screen to wait for me see the output.

What is the difference between the two files that i get error while sending one and not while sending the other?

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question. You can edit your question any times!

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

\t is treated as a tab character. Change the name of the file from tc to something else which doesn't start with t and it will work fine.